# purify captions

Tags: captions

I'm inserting graphics in an article and want to use the figure-environment; but I would like to omit the *figure nn:* expression and only read the text of the caption. I succeeded in renewing the `\thefigure`-command to yield just nothing. But the colon remains and I want it to vanish. What is your advice?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you try loading the `caption` package and typing `\caption*{...}` instead of `\caption{...}`?

Comment: ...or use `\captionsetup[labelformat=empty,labelsep=none]{caption}` (Disclaimer: Shameless self-advertisement)

Comment: I have an additional answer to those referenced. How is the current questioner meant to know about that especially as I think my answer covers more generic cases, not just tables and figures?

Comment: @PeterWilson: How about answering it in the linked source?

Comment: @Werner I did, haven't you seen it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{textonly}{#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=textonly}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}

\caption{A figure that explains nothing}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was searching.